# Adding new layer of children in a Tree

Tags: java, tree, nodes

I'm making a Tree and have been able to implement setting the Parent and child properly. I'm stuck at attempting to make a new layer of the tree, a grandchild in this case. It isn't a binary tree. Ideally I'd like to place the implementation of the new layer in either the constructor or in the addChild method. The following is what I have for my set up and the methods setting up my Parent and Children in my Tree

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class TreeNode {

static int count; // store # tree nodes created. Generate IDs

private String id;// unique id # of nodes.

private List<TreeNode> children; // store all children of node

private TreeNode parent; // reference parent of the node. Null is node is root

public TreeNode(List<TreeNode> children) {

    this.children = children;
    this.count++;
    this.id = Integer.toString(this.count);
    int ctr = 0;
    if (children != null) {
        while (ctr < children.size()) {
            children.get(ctr).setParent(this);
            ctr++;
        }
    }
}

public void addChild(TreeNode child) { // add single child to current node

    if (this.getChildren() == null) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.setChildren(new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    else {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is the class `abstract`?  (I can't see an intent or a reason to extend it.)

Perhaps I don't understand what you're asking;  from where I'm sitting, you already have support for "a new layer of the tree" -- as many as you want, in fact (at least of the class weren't `abstract`)...

```
TreeNode grandparent = new TreeNode(new ArrayList<TreeNode>());  // I recommend a zero-arg constructor that does this

TreeNode child = new TreeNode(new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
grandparent.addChild(child);

TreeNode grandchild = new TreeNode(new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
child.addChild(grandchild);
```

You now have a 3-level tree.

### More Suggestions

#### Your `id` field

What is the purpose of the `id` filed?  As you have it, you could get duplicates in a multi-threaded context.  Better would be...

```
this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Every `TreeNode` would receive a unique id for certain (though they wouldn't be numeric or sequential).

Also, `id` values based on `UUID` will be unique *even if* you restart your VM and you're using persistent `TreeNode` objects.

#### The loop in your constructor

Better than...

```
while (ctr < children.size()) {
    children.get(ctr).setParent(this);
    ctr++;
}
```

would be...

```
for (TreeNode child : children) {
    child.setParent(this);
}
```

Comment: oh I see. I was having trouble seeing that that's what I had. Was asking TAs for explanation of it, and it was all super vague and unclear. As for the abstract, I actually have another class that uses this class and implements other methods using this structure.  For this challenge I was given the face that the TreeNode class is abstract.   How does the class being abstract change the implementation of a new level  in this case?